# XAML how to show gridview in one column?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview

Here my XAML Code

```
<Page
x:Class="GridView_Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:GridView_Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:GridView_Test.Model"
mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Song" x:Key="SongItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind ThumbImage}" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Songs}"  Name="grid1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SongItemTemplate}" >

    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

[image: How it looks now]

I need to make items in one column, like listview. By default in gridview items shows like in table, by I need a list. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use a ListView then?

Comment: @Bart Thanks, works great. How make fill all listview with stack panel? make 100% width?

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is showing like this because the gridview needs to be assigned to some **Row**? Add Grid.Row Property to the **GridView** as shown in the code below

```
<Page
x:Class="GridView_Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:GridView_Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:GridView_Test.Model"
mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Song" x:Key="SongItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind ThumbImage}" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Songs}" Grid.Row="0"  Name="grid1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SongItemTemplate}" >

    </GridView>
</Grid>
```